# Angular 8 Material mat-error shows up on load by default

Tags: angular9

I am having this weird scenario. my mat-error shows up by default, without even touching the input field. Basically, when I load the page the error message is shown without any user interaction on the input field. I don't have any error messages on the browser console. Can anyone point out what did I miss?

This is my .ts

```
frmStep3: FormGroup;
  matcher = new MyErrorStateMatcher();
// omited unrelated code 
       this.frmStep3 = this.fb.group({
          courseDurationNum: [, [Validators.required, Validators.maxLength(3), Validators.minLength(1)]]
       
        });
      return {
         frmStep3: this.frmStep3
        };
```

This is my HTML

```
 <form class="form-group-parent p-0" [formGroup]="frmStep3" (ngSubmit)="stepForward()">
            <div class="form-group d-inline-block">
              <label class="w-100">Choose your course duration<sup>*</sup></label>
              <input [errorStateMatcher]="matcher" [maxLength]="3" type="text" class="float-left" matInput
                formControlName="courseDurationNum" placeholder="Ex. 1 - 365 Day(s)" />
              <mat-error class="w-100 float-left"
                *ngIf="frmStep3.get('courseDurationNum').hasError('required') || frmStep3.get('courseDurationNum').invalid">
                <strong>Duration</strong> must be between <strong>1 - 365</strong> day(s).
              </mat-error>

            </div>         
          </form>
```

Answer (score 1):

I figured out, I missed wrapping them in from controls in `<mat-form-field>` tag. Correct code below.

```
 <form class="form-group-parent p-0" [formGroup]="frmStep3" (ngSubmit)="stepForward()">
            <div class="form-group d-inline-block">
<mat-form-field>
              <label class="w-100">Choose your course duration<sup>*</sup></label>
              <input [errorStateMatcher]="matcher" [maxLength]="3" type="text" class="float-left" matInput
                formControlName="courseDurationNum" placeholder="Ex. 1 - 365 Day(s)" />
              <mat-error class="w-100 float-left"
                *ngIf="frmStep3.get('courseDurationNum').hasError('required') || frmStep3.get('courseDurationNum').invalid">
                <strong>Duration</strong> must be between <strong>1 - 365</strong> day(s).
              </mat-error>
</mat-form-field>
            </div>         
          </form>
```